# Zokrates backend "gm17" not supported

Tags: zokrates

I am trying to experiment with ZoKrates library. When I use ./zokrates setup command, it warns me about gm16 malleability. So, I tried to change the proving scheme to gm17. But I keep getting the error "Backend gm17 not supported". Anyone faced this issue before? I am using MacOS. I see that gm17 requires libsnark. I checked in libsnark's github repo if they have instructions for activating libsnark in Mac. But, I don't see any instructions.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

GM 17 is the only backend that is supported by default. To enable GM16 (and PHGR13) you would have to build Zokrates from source using the appropriate flags.

`cargo +nightly -Z package-features build --release --package zokrates_cli --features="libsnark"`

There is a gotcha for installing this on Mac OS. OSX does not support Super Cop which is a  build dependency for libsnark, so you would have to disable it in the build configuration.

https://github.com/Zokrates/ZoKrates/blob/f01fc7e627fb8c3f38774ec8bde6858ece8dbec6/zokrates_core/build.rs#L41

```
  let libsnark = cmake::Config::new(libsnark_source_path)
            .define("WITH_SUPERCOP", "OFF") ==> Add this line. 
            .define("WITH_PROCPS", "OFF")
            .define("CURVE", "ALT_BN128")
            .define("USE_PT_COMPRESSION", "OFF")
            .define("MONTGOMERY_OUTPUT", "ON")
            .define("BINARY_OUTPUT", "ON")
            .build();
```

Another thing to remember is that you need to add the right flag for the setup,  generate proof , export verifier commands i.e `--proving-scheme(or -s) gm17`

```
./zokrates setup --proving-scheme gm17
./zokrates generate-proof -s gm17
./zokrates export-verifier -s gm17
```

#### Reference:

- Zokrates Documentation: https://zokrates.github.io/reference/proving_schemes.html#supporting-backends